# Selenium Replicating mouse Movement & clicking

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am relatively new to Selenium and it's capabilities So far I have found it's just the tool to use for automated regression testing for a web application.  And it's for this regression testing suite that I am in the process of building that I have come to a problem.  In the web app I have a page that displays a Jquery Datatable with some rows in it.  Each row is bound with a context menu.  That pop's up as a DIV floating on the top most Z-order, with absolute positioning all controlled with Jquery.

What I am attempting to do in selenium is to physically use this menu so that I am able to warp it with the appropriate regression tests.  I have has some success with using the Actions class to call the context menu up.  What I am not able to do is to have the mouse move to the menu Items can click them.  I have been trying to use the MoveByOffset method but I don't seem to be having any luck in getting it to click on anything in the menu.  I also have had no luck in working out where on the page the mouse is currently located thus not able to prove is anything is actually happening.

any help or advise on this will be gratefully received.

Thanking you all in-advance.

---

This is the code that I am currently using to attempt to drive this context menu.  the values in the MoveByOffset have literally been every combination of 10 & -10.  to try and hit the first menu item.

```
public void ClickAction_myPOTSIcontextmenu(IWebElement Row)
        {
            Actions builder = new Actions(this._driver);

            IAction action = builder.MoveToElement(Row).ContextClick().MoveByOffset(-10,-10).Click().Build();
            action.Perform();
        }
```

Comment: Could you show an example of the Action Chains you've attempted? The Actions class is powerful but it can be tricky to learn.

Comment: I have updated my main question with the code that I am trying to use.  Might be too simple for it's own good.

Comment: Thanks for that, very helpful.
When using the `.MoveByOffest()`, through experimentation, I have discovered that the pixels moved are from the pointers position in the prior `elements` position. So sometimes the `MoveByOffset()` will need to take this into account. However, since you say that a `DIV element` is revealed - are there normal `elements` contained within the `div` that you could locate and interact with that way? eg: `builder.MoveToElement(Row).MoveToElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("id").Click().Build().Perform();`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("selector_for_element"));
        Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) element;
        Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
        mouse.click(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
```